# Inserting text below and above a matched pattern

Tags: regex, perl, unix, sed, awk

First of all, thanks for such a wonderful community we have!! I have always been benefited by the great knowledge shared here on stackoverflow.

Coming to the problem I was facing:

I have a bunch of files(about 200) In those files I wanted to search for a pattern(multi-line) and if the pattern matches, I want to add some text above and below the pattern.

E.g

File1.cpp

```
#ifndef FILE1_H
#define FILE1_H

#ifndef PARENT1_H
#include "Parent1.h"
#endif

#ifndef SIBLING_H
#include "Sibling.h"
#endif

#ifndef PARENT2_H
#include "Parent2.h"
#endif

class File1
{
};

#endif
```

In this file I wanted to add `#ifndef NOPARENT` above `#ifndef PARENT1_H` and `#endif` below `#endif` which is right below `Parent1.h`.

I want to do the same thing for `#ifndef PARENT2_H`

So the output will look like:

```
#ifndef FILE1_H
#define FILE1_H

#ifndef NOPARENT
#ifndef PARENT1_H
#include "Parent1.h"
#endif
#endif


#ifndef SIBLING_H
#include "Sibling.h"
#endif

#ifndef NOPARENT
#ifndef PARENT2_H
#include "Parent2.h"
#endif
#endif

class File1
{
};

#endif
```

I have a list of such matches. For e.g here I was searching for PARENT1_H, PARENT2_H etc but I have more like GRANDPARENT1_H, GREATGRANDPARENT_H etc

So essentially, the approach I was thinking is, search for the input symbols(`PARENT1_H` etc) in those files and if a match is found, add the text(`#ifndef NOPARENT`) above and `#endif` below.

Input symbols are many and so are the files in which to replace.

Can anyone please help me with a script which does this using sed/awk/perl. Or any other language/script(bash etc) would also be great!

I am novice user of sed/awk/perl so could use the help

Thanks a lot :-)

Best Regards,
Marc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Did not read correctly request.
This seems to give correct O/P

```
awk '/PARENT1_H/ {print "#ifndef NOPARENT" RS $0;f=1} /#endif/ && f {print $0;f=0} !/PARENT1_H/' file
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This was very helpful. I used this and worked great for me!

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '/#ifndef (PARENT1_H|PARENT2_H)$/{print "#ifndef NOPARENT"; f=1} {print} f&&/#endif/{print; f=0}' file
#ifndef FILE1_H
#define FILE1_H

#ifndef NOPARENT
#ifndef PARENT1_H
#include "Parent1.h"
#endif
#endif

#ifndef SIBLING_H
#include "Sibling.h"
#endif

#ifndef NOPARENT
#ifndef PARENT2_H
#include "Parent2.h"
#endif
#endif

class File1
{
};

#endif
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! This was very helpful. I used this and worked great for me.

Comment: Remember to click on the check mark next to the answer if you're happy with it so others don't waste their time trying to come up with alternatives for you.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a regex? Let me know if this is not what you want and I'll modify!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $file = 'file1.txt';
open my $input, '<', $file or die "Can't read $file: $!";

my $outfile = 'output.txt';
open my $output, '>', $outfile or die "Can't write to $outfile: $!";

while(<$input>){
    chomp;
my (@match) = ($_ =~ /\.*?(\s+PARENT\d+_H)/); # edit - only matches 'PARENT' not 'GRANDPARENT'
    if (@match){
        print $output "#ifndef NOPARENT\n";
        print $output "$_\n";
        print $output "#endif\n";
    }
    else {print $output "$_\n"}
}
```

Output:

```
#ifndef FILE1_H
#define FILE1_H

#ifndef NOPARENT
#ifndef PARENT1_H
#endif
#include "Parent1.h"
#endif

#ifndef SIBLING_H
#include "Sibling.h"
#endif

#ifndef NOPARENT
#ifndef PARENT2_H
#endif
#include "Parent2.h"
#endif
```

Comment: #endif at wrong location, se O/P request.
_#endif below #endif which is right below Parent1.h_